# How can I set topic when I use ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory?

Tags: spring-kafka

Is there any way I can set the topic when I use concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory? I don't want to any annotation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not going to use `@KafkaListener`, you don't need to worry about that factory. The target `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainer` is enough for you.

There you can find `ContainerProperties` for configuration.